# Does PHP PDO escapes HTML automatically?

Tags: php, html, pdo

So I have this wired problem with my codes. I use a WYSIWYG editor inside on of my projects and save the content ( which has HTML from the editor inside itself ) onto a Database. I use a simple code like whats below.

It works perfectly on my local computer but on the server ( cPanel hosting with litespeed ) The saved HTML on the Database has all the `"` characters escaped to `\"` like `<a href="something">` to `<a href=\"something\">`

But I can't figure out why.

```
try{
    $query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE table SET code=:code");

    $pdo->beginTransaction();

    $query->bindParam(':code',$code);
    $query->execute();

    $pdo->commit();
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'ERROR: '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

UPDATE : The problem was with [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).  Disabling It needs the access to `PHP.ini`. But Updating the `PHP` to a version newer than `5.4.0` will also do.

Comment: It's not PDO that's doing that. It's PHP's evil ['magic quotes'](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).

Comment: So how do I make It NOT do It's Evil Deeds?

Comment: Click the link and read what it says ffs the 4th option is "Disabling Magic Quotes"

Comment: Yes But I Probably don't have access to php_ini.

Comment: Tell your hosting provider to provide decent hosting. magic quotes have been bad and deprecated for years. It has to be set in `php.ini` or `htaccess`, everything else is too late.

Comment: Thanks for the Tips. I had the option to upgrade PHP to '5.4.0' And that did the trick. Much Appreciated again.